# Put placeholder and default value in yassnippet

Tags: yasnippet

I would like to create a yassnippet with a placeholder, so something like

`value = $1(insert_value)`

with the meaning that I would like to see the text "insert value" but when I press TAB and then type something, the text is replaced.

I would also like that the placeholder actually becomes a real text if I do not press TAB or I press TAB twice.

How these things can me done?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you describe is provided by [placeholder fields](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3-4), such as
`${1:default value}`.  After pressing tab once to navigate to the
field, you can type a replacement value.  Or you can hit tab again to
keep the default.